# Does a processor perform speculative execution on a function pointer table?

Tags: c, speculative-execution

If one has a function pointer table, and the index is provided as a volatile variable, will the generated code be considered branchless, and this avoid speculative execution, or will the processor still attempt to speculate the most likely branch?

As a simple example, consider:

```
if (input_value > thresh) {
    do_this();
} else {
    do_that();
}
```

I predict a CPU with speculative execution will try what it thinks is the most likely branch for the above code.

However, if converted into a jump table:

```
this_or_that[input > thresh]();
```

Will the above code still trigger speculative execution?

Comment: That depends on the compiler and the platform. From my knowledge gcc does it but the implementation i mostly use (baremetal ARM) ignores this during the code generation stages.

Comment: Yes, it's called, "Branch Target Prediction". And it is one of the Spectre attack vectors.

Comment: @Mysticial: Thanks, is this still tracked by the prediction history table (PHT), or is it tracked differently? I was reading about the BranchScope attack, and Intel gave a terse response about *side channel resistant* code. I wondered if this meant code that lacked prediction history.

Comment: The details likely vary by processor. But the answer is probably yes. The processor will track the destination addresses of indirect branches. But to what extent I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the commonality of compiler generated jump tables, I would say it would be rather short-sighted if the CPU designers failed to track branching through such tables. That said, not all CPU's are equally capable so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both cases will be executed speculatively. You mentioned "jump table" actually is an indirect call. The indirect call is also traced by morden CPU. The predictor can predict the call target via BTB and execute the target speculatively.